# Yii2 create two signup form?

Tags: php, yii2

I have to create 2 signup form for different user but,I have use one table for both signup form. table is 'User' but in both form some field are different and table is same for both.But when I validate first form that time second form also validate.please help me I am new in yii2.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-signup']); ?>

                    <?= $form->field($model, 'username') ?>

                    <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>

                    <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary pull-right">
                    <strong>Signup User</strong>
                    </button>

                    </div>

                <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-signup']); ?>

                    <?= $form->field($model2, 'fname') ?>
                    <?= $form->field($model2, 'mname') ?>
                    <?= $form->field($model2, 'lname') ?>
                    <?= $form->field($model2, 'username') ?>
                    <?= $form->field($model2, 'email') ?>
                    <?= $form->field($model2, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>  
                    <?= $form->field($model2, 'designation') ?> 
                    <?= $form->field($model2, 'contact_no') ?>
<button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-success pull-right">
             <strong>Signup Vendor</strong>
             </button>
              <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['username', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
            ['username', 'required'],
            ['fname', 'required'],
            ['mname', 'required'],
            ['lname', 'required'],
            ['username', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'],
            ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],

            ['email', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
            ['email', 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],
            ['email', 'string', 'max' => 255],
            ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],

            ['password', 'required'],
            ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6],
            ['designation', 'required'],
            ['designation', 'string', 'max' => 100],
            ['contact_no', 'required'],
            ['contact_no', 'number', 'max' => 12],
        ];
    }
public function actionSignup()
    {
        $model = new SignupForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if ($user = $model->signup()) {
                return $this->redirect(['login']);
                if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                }
            }
        }
       $model2 = new SignupForm2();
        if ($model2->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if ($user = $model2->signup()) {
                return $this->redirect(['login']);
                if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->render('signup', [
            'model' => $model,
            'model2' => $model2,
        ]);
    }
```

Now It's Work,I am create 2 **signupForm.php** in front end models.and in **siteController** create two models in **actionSignup**
 [image]validate

Comment: both form's id must be different in order to validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change id in `Active::begin`

```
...
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-signup-one']); ?>

... 

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-signup-two']); ?>

...
```

Comment: I give id to the form as per you code but yet problem as it is,..And one think tell me I have to create 2 signupForm ?

Comment: After click on 1st signup button it is validate firstname,middlename,lastname

Comment: remove `id` and then try, don't pass any argument to `begin()` like below `<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>` in both the forms.  Not giving id will auto generate id like `w0`, `w1`, `w2` and so on. Check by right clicking and inspecting elements.

Comment: Now,It's work I do some changes I will upload it ...Thanks

Comment: Please vote to answer it's really help full for others.